# How should we tag questions about the 2009 Star Trek movie and any successors?

Tags: tags, discussion

When looking up tags for Star Trek, I've found the following:

[star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek)
[star-trek-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos)
[star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng)
[star-trek-ds9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-ds9)
[star-trek-voyager](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-voyager)
[star-trek-enterprise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-enterprise) (Newly created by myself.)

One thing I see missing though, as long as we have these sub-category tags, is a tag for questions pertaining to the new timeline created by the 2009 movie.  How should we tag this?

A couple ideas:

[star-trek-2009](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2009)  (For the release of the movie that started it all.)
[star-trek-jja](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-jja) (For J.J. Abrams.)
[star-trek-reboot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-reboot) (Suggested by @TonyMeyer.)

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely not J.J. Abrams. Assuming there does end up being more than two movies in the rebooted series, naming the tag after the director of the first (and most likely second) movie doesn't really make any sense.

Looking forward, 2009 seems rather obscure as well. In 2015, when the third movie comes out, do people really want to remember what year the first one was?

I don't see much need for any specific tag right now. Remember that tags are all about following distinct sets of questions. Are there really people interested in following questions about the single (at this point, plus pre-production sequel) movie and not any other Trek?

If there is, I would suggest [star-trek-reboot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-reboot).

Comment: I may have blundered in my answer somewhat.  Are the 4 votes for the "we don't need a tag now" part, the "definitely not JJ/2009" part, or the "star-trek-reboot" part?

Answer (score 1):

I think since none of the other Star Trek movies have their own tags, we would leave it alone. Also, I doubt there will be confusion as it is the only movie named just Star Trek. All the others have sub titles like The Motion Picture, Nemesis, Wrath of Kahn, etc.

Comment: I think one reason the other movies don't have their own tags is because each could be tagged for the TV series represented in the movie.  In the case of ST2k9, there is no TV series to lump it together with.  Also, I think it does create enough of a special case that it and its successors should have their own tag.  If we simply leave them under a generic [tag:star-trek] category, we're essentially saying the other more specific tags are superfluous as well.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other movie arcs are tagged in a special manner: there is no [star-trek-tng-movies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng-movies) or [star-trek-tos-movies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos-movies) tag. If they're about a movie, they should be tagged with the movie name or just tagged [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek). That is, if *Star Trek* needs to be broken out from general [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) questions, they should all be broken out:

- *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* becomes [star-trek-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-1) ← [star-trek-motion-picture](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-motion-picture)
- *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan* becomes [star-trek-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2) ← [star-trek-wrath-of-khan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-wrath-of-khan)
- *Star Trek III: The Search for Spock* becomes [star-trek-3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-3)  (no synonym, too long)
- *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home* becomes [star-trek-4](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-4)  ← [star-trek-voyage-home](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-voyage-home)
- *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier* becomes [star-trek-5](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-5) ← [star-trek-final-frontier](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-final-frontier)
- *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country* becomes [star-trek-6](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-6) (no synonym, too long)
- *Star Trek: Generations* becomes [star-trek-7](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-7) ← [star-trek-generations](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-generations)
- *Star Trek: First Contact* becomes [star-trek-8](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-8) ← [star-trek-first-contact](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-first-contact)
- *Star Trek: Insurrection* becomes [star-trek-9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-9) ← [star-trek-insurrection](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-insurrection)
- *Star Trek: Nemesis* becomes [star-trek-10](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-10) ← [star-trek-nemesis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-nemesis)
- *Star Trek* becomes [star-trek-11](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-11)  ← [star-trek-2009](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2009)

Speculating about a general tag for a possible TV series isn't really appropriate: there's zero evidence that such a TV series is even being considered, much less that we're going to have questions about it. If a new series comes out, we can tag questions about it with the series name, whatever it happens to be.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally agree with (re)tagging all of the questions per each individual movie.  The only reason I'm asking about ST2k9 is because I believe its timeline and canon deviates far enough from the rest of the Star Trek universe to warrant a category of its own (which would also include any sequels or TV series made from it).

Comment: @Iszi None of the other movie arcs are tagged in a special manner: there is no [tag:star-trek-tng-movies] or [tag:star-trek-tos-movies] tag. If they're about a movie, they should be tagged with the movie name or just tagged [tag:star-trek]. Speculating about a general tag for a possible TV series isn't really appropriate: there's zero evidence that such a TV series is even being considered, much less that we're going to have questions about it. If a new series comes out, we can tag questions about it with the series name, whatever it happens to be.

Comment: If there are movie-specific tags, then I think this is a good set.  However, is there really any need to have the movie-specific tags as well as the general [tag:star-trek]?  Are there really (e.g.) fans of STII and STVI who want to avoid questions about ST:TMP and ST:X?

Comment: @TonyMeyer This question is working under the premise that people *do* want to break them out. If we are going to break them out, we don't need to invent a franchise tag for *Star Trek* (2009): it should just be tagged with the movie name.