# What is the tag for the Star Trek Abramsverse timeline?

Tags: discussion

Yes, this is a repeat of [How should we tag questions about the 2009 Star Trek movie and any successors?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/905/3823)

But I don't believe it was resolved, and that question was asked before release of STID so it was more theoretical at the time.

To me, there is definitely a gap here.

Questions about TOS and TOS-era movies are tagged [star-trek-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos)

Questions about TNG and TNG-era movies are tagged [star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng)

Using the tag [star-trek-2009](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2009) doesn't make sense for question about the Abramsverse, including ST2009, STID and any future movies taking place in that timeline.

Comment: It strikes me that that tag wiki for [tag:Star-Trek-2009] should simply be updated to make it clear that it covers all of the films in the abramverse

Comment: Why not revise the tag and call it star-trek-ntl, for New Time Line. This makes it clear that as long as this particular set of actors and creators are producing material, it would fall under the -ntl tag?

Comment: @Thaddeus - Because no-one would know what the acronym meant.

Comment: Add the notes to the wiki for the tag. Star Trek 2009 doesn't really tell me anything about what the tag should mean, does it? Isn't that what the wiki notes are for? "New Time Line" how hard is that to understand? Honestly, is it any more difficult to understand that Star Trek -TOS, -TNG, -DS9, -VOY or -ENT? I am NOT an advocate for RETAINING the star-trek-2009 tag. I am advocating for replacing it with star-trek-ntl (new time line) tag.

Comment: @Thaddeus:   using star-trek-2009 is confusing and inaccurate -- it clearly is a reference to a movie not a new universe.

Comment: There seems to be a trend towards tagging movies individually; we have [tag:star-trek-first-contact], recently a bunch more for the older movies, and [tag:star-trek-2009] and [tag:star-trek-into-darkness]. Is there a need for a more general tag?

Comment: @JasonBaker:   Personally, I believe so.   There is a lot of activity on Star Trek, and questions definitely do have to do with the alternate timeline rather than either ST2009 or STID specifically.

Comment: Incidentally, [tag:mirror-universe] exists.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: “using star-trek-2009 is confusing and inaccurate -- it clearly is a reference to a movie not a new universe”. Maybe. Although the 2009 movie ‘Star Trek’ is actually the *only* movie called ‘Star Trek’, so suffixing it with ‘2009’ is kind of unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite We already have a general [tag:Star-Trek] tag though.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: very true — suffixing the movie tag here is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Per @DrRDizzle's suggestion at the end, the tag for this universe makes sense.
It should be [star-trek-reboot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-reboot)

Comment: Please vote here if you support this concept.

Comment: You should have added a `[here](...)` link to make it clear that you mean the post, not the comment ;)

Comment: @ThePopMachine : This was a good question, and I support the creation of the **star-trek-reboot** tag for this purpose.  My only cautionary note is in regard to re-tagging old questions: in cases where the maximum number of tags has already been applied (i.e. 5 tags), one should think carefully before removing a tag to accommodate a new one.  Even if **star-trek-reboot** applies, the tags that are already there may be more useful and/or relevant.  Just something to consider... :-)

Comment: @Praxis, noted.   Going to give this a few more days for comment, and then help with the retags appreciated.   My personal plan would be to add the tag to questions related to the creation of the timeline and differences between those movies and the original TOS universe,  but not automatically to any question related to ST2009 or STID.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Sounds like a good plan. :-)

Comment: I oppose 'Star Trek Reboot' as it isn't a reboot.

Answer (score 6):

**Simply tag them with the movie(s) they are referring to.**

I see no reason that questions about *Star Trek* (2009) shouldn't just be tagged with the [star-trek-2009](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2009) tag, and questions about *Star Trek Into Darkness* shouldn't just be tagged with [star-trek-into-darkness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-into-darkness). Questions about both would simply use both tags, and questions about the upcoming sequel to *Star Trek Into Darkness* would use a film specific tag for that.

The reason for this is that unlike the various "cinematic universe" tags we have (such as the [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) tag, the new Star Trek films are not a "cinematic universe" as such thanks to the fact that they are just a series of films, with no spin off or related material to ask about.

Should a spin-off film or TV series be announced then this will need rethinking, but for now we should treat them the same way as we would treat any other series of films.

EDIT: It looks like the new Star Trek films **do** in fact have related materials. As such, I would suggest a new tag to be used when referring to this new franchise, something like [star-trek-reboot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-reboot).   Please use the other answer to upvote this solution.

Comment: ...there is related material.  A series of comic books set in the new timeline.  And we treat other series of films by often creating a franchise tag.

Comment: @Keen I didn't know that. Will update answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 For the [tag:star-trek-reboot], not the movie-specific ones.

Comment: This doesn't allow people to express their opinion because you have both options in your answer.   I'm going to remove the mention here and add a new answer so people can vote appropriately.

Comment: A vote here means "just tag for the specific movie"

Comment: Although we're not quite there yet, we may soon be entering the reboot of the reboot phase of cinema, so I think keeping the year (at least when a particular identity or series started) makes more sense in the long run.

Comment: Depends on if the title used is unique. There was no need to use [tag:The-Amazing-Spider-Man-2012] because the old series was simple called [tag:Spider-Man].

Comment: @DrRDizzle:   So what's the tag for the 'spider-man' universe as opposed to the 'the-amazing-spider-man-2012' universe?  ;)

Comment: @ThePopMachine This is why I argued in favour of the solo film tags initially. Not every series of films is a "universe", and shouldn't be treated as such.

Comment: @DrRDizzle:  Yeah, that was semi-in-jest because 'spider-man' is the tag for a character, not a universe.   And I accept your point, but in the case of [tag:star-trek-reboot] there is clearly a universe which needs tagging (IMO)